Unable to create resources like blobs, keyvault & app services within Azure B2C tenant
I guess I have successfully linked my Azure B2C tenant with existing active subscription. I'm able to see Subscribtion id in Azure B2C overview. Even Identity Experience Framework is enabled in Azure AD B2C policies. But still I'm unable to create resources like blob storage or keyvault within B2C tenant.
Even though subscription id linked to b2c tenant when I click on keyvault it redirects to screen where it says Welcome to Azure!
Don't have a subscription? Check out the following options.

you cant create resource in a B2C tenant

Am I missing anything?

yeah b2c tenant is just for user auth. also you should consider using external identities rather than b2c: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/faq-customers

Like b2c is the old stuff

B2C only allows B2C functionality, e.g. user flows, to be configured, plus some other Entra functionality, e.g. conditional access.
But for everything else, you have to use your primary Entra tenant.
It also does not allow any SaaS configuration e.g. M365.
